# debugging LibreOffice scriptforge python with pycharm on Windows 11

Tags: python, pycharm, libreoffice, uno

I have created a python project in:

```
C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\LibreOffice\4\user\Scripts\python\propertyManager
```

I tried to create the project with:
venv:
C:\Users%USER%\AppData\Roaming\LibreOffice\4\user\Scripts\python\propertyManager\venv-w
interpreter:

```
C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\python.exe
```

but I get an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Program Files\\LibreOffice\\program\\python-core-3.8.16\\bin\\pythonw.exe'
```

Comment: How are you running your code? Did you source the virtual environment?

Comment: I am running the code from PyCharm as well as from LibreOffice. LibreOffice is working fine (I assume it is handling its own environment).  Its PyCharm I'm having issues with.  Since I am running from the IDE, I don't have to source the environment.

Comment: What are the script path and working directory set to?

Comment: In PyCharm I had been using the default paths (but your post made me think....)  I just tried adding "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\python-core-3.8.16" to the interpreter path but it didn't help